# R XML - Error attemping to add Node to Internal Node

Tags: xml, r

I am reading an XML file using R and the XML package.  It is my wish to read in the XML document, perform some stat calculations and insert the results back into the XML document as a child node and then save the updated XML file to a new location.

Here's an illustrative example.  The XML file I'm reading (insert_node_error.xml):

```
<library>
    <book>
        <title>Book1</title>
        <author>AuthorA</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Book2</title>
        <author>AuthorB</author>
    </book>     
</library>
```

Here is the code that I'm running:

```
#load file
file.name <- "xml\\insert_node_error.xml"
input.xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(file.name)

#produce list of books in library (my actual code has loops and calcs here)
books.xml <- getNodeSet(input.xml, "//book")

#set price for first book as "price" node
price.xml <- xmlNode("price", 19.99)

#attempt to insert that price as child within the first book node
books.xml[[1]] <- addChildren(books.xml[[1]], price.xml)
```

The output has appended the node but has stripped all the XML out of it and is supplying only text.

```
> input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
  <book><title>Book1</title><author>AuthorA</author>pricetext19.99</book>
  <book>
    <title>Book2</title>
    <author>AuthorB</author>
  </book>
</library>
```

I would like to see:

```
<library>
    <book>
        <title>Book1</title>
        <author>AuthorA</author>
    <price>19.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Book2</title>
        <author>AuthorB</author>
    </book>     
</library>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a bit of trial and error. Your xmlNode looked good....

```
library(XML)
#load file
file.name <- "insert_node_error.xml"
input.xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(file.name)

#produce list of books in library (my actual code has loops and calcs here)
books.xml <- getNodeSet(input.xml, "//book")

price.xml <- xmlNode("price", 19.99)

#set price for first book as "price" node
top = newXMLNode("price",19.99)

#attempt to insert that price as child within the first book node
books.xml[[1]] = addChildren(books.xml[[1]], top)
books.xml
```

Comment: Dieter -- thank you so much!  Works perfectly and I'm not sure I ever would have found/considered the newXMLNode function.  Cheers!

Comment: Dieter -- did so.  Cannot mark as useful as I haven't the reputation.

Comment: You have! And your question was perfectly formulated and should be given extra credit. Keep with us.